# Double integration

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$
>  \iint \limits_R(2xy+9) \;\mathrm{d}A
> $$ 
>   where $R$ is the region bounded by $y=x^2$ and $y=x+2$.

I have drawn my picture and have come up with my regions from $\sqrt{y}$ to $(y-2)$ for $\mathrm{d}x$ and $0$ to $4$ for $\mathrm{d}y$, but I seem to be computing these wrong though. Or are my bounds wrong?

Comment: Try solving for the $ \ x-$ coordinates of the intersection points between the two curves:  I think you'll find that you're complicating your work by looking at integation in the $ \ y-$ direction.  (The bounds on $ \ y \ $ are right, but you have to change the bounding curves along the interval.)

Comment: could my dx bounds be -1 to 2? This one is confusing me

Comment: Yes, and going in the $ \ x-$ direction, the line is always the "upper curve" and the parabola is always the "lower" one.  In the $ \ y-$ direction, over $ \ [0, \ 1] \ $ , you have to integrate from $ \ -\sqrt{y} \ $ to $ \ \sqrt{y} \ $ , and then over $ \ [1, \ 4] \ $ you have to switch to integrating from $ \ y - 2 \ $ to $ \ \sqrt{y} \ $ . (It isn't _wrong_ to do the latter; it's just more work. You should get the same result either way.)

Comment: I think I am confusing what your saying. So my equation would look like (2x+9)dxdy from-1 to 2 dy and 0 to 4, I don't know if I am getting the bounds right

Comment: To integrate between the "upper" line and the "lower" parabola between $ \ x = -1 \ $ and $ \ x = 2 \ $ , your double integral would be  $$ \ \int_{-1}^2 \int_{x^2}^{x+2} \ (2xy \ + \ 9) \ \ dy \   dx \ \ . $$  $ \ y \ $ is going from the parabola "up" to the line, _then_ $ \ x \ $ is going from $ \ -1 \ $ to $ \ 2 \ $

Answer (score 2):

In order to find the bounds we have to find the values of $x$ for which $y=x^2$ and $y=x+2$ are equivalent. To do this set the equations equal to each and solve the quadratic $x^2=x+2$:

$$x^2-x-2=0 \implies (x-2)(x+1)=0 \implies x=-1,2 \implies y=1,4$$

Now it is a choice of whether you want to integrate over $y$ or $x$ first. By the looks of it you want to use $x$ first, but I highly recommend integrating over $y$ first:

$$\int_{-1}^2 \int_{x^2}^{x+2} (2xy+9)dydx = \int_{-1}^2 \Big( xy^2+9y \Big) \Big|_{x^2}^{x+2} dx = \int_{-1}^2 \Big( (x(x+2)^2+9(x+2)) - (x^5+9x^2) \Big) dx = \int_{-1}^2 (-x^5+x^3-5x^2+13x+18) dx = \frac{207}{4}$$

Notice that integrating over $y$ first led me to saying that the bottom curve is always the same on the interval and so is the top curve. Equivalently we can integrate over $x$ first to attain the same solution, but it will take more work since there is a split required in the bounds:

$$\int_0^1 \int_{-\sqrt{y}}^\sqrt{y} (2xy+9y)dxdy + \int_1^4 \int_{y-2}^\sqrt{y} (2xy+9y)dxdy$$

Specifically it is the left curve that switches at $y=1$. Below this line it is defined by $x=-\sqrt{y}$ and above by $x=y-2$. It is up to you whether you want to evaluate two double integrals or one, but the first method is definitely the easier choice.

Comment: Well done!   +1....

Comment: The pair of integrals produce terms $ \ 12 \ + \ \frac{159}{4} \ = \ \frac{207}{4} \ $ , so the two alternative integrations agree.